# Элементы помимо li внутри ul

Tags: теги, html

Можно ли внутрь `<ul>` засунуть, допустим, `<div>`?

Браузер, вроде бы, отображает, но правильно ли это?

Answer (score 7):

Если следовать [спецификации](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/lists.html#h-10.2), то тег `UL` может содержать только элементы `LI`.